# animation with jquery, moving element

Tags: animation

I have a problem with animation in jquery. I want to make an element smaller after time (1second) and then move this to the bottom (20px).
What am i doing wrong?

```
$(function(){

    var box = $('box');

    box.delay(1000).animate({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    }, 3000, function(){

        box.animate({

            top: "+=20",
           }, 3000);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/b4qjagwt/

However, I think you meant to select `#box` not `box`, is that right? There is no `<box>` element.

For the element to move down, you have two options:

1. Make the `box` element have `position: relative`
2. Use a top margin: `"margin-top": "+= 20"`

Using relative positioning will mean the element may overflow onto something else. I don't know what your page looks like, but you can try both and see which works best.